# Truffle test gives "Error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address ___ is not a contract address"

Tags: javascript, json, ethereum, solidity, truffle

When I run `truffle test` on terminal I get the following error `Error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0x3ad2c00512808bd7fafa6dce844a583621f3df87 is not a contract address` I don't understand why I get this because my `build` folder is normal meaning if I run `truffle migrate --reset` the address in the terminal is the same as the address in the build file. when I run truffle migrate it works. Also, every time I run the truffle test the recipient address always changes. I don't know what do to please help.

One other thing this only happens once I use the code `selfdestruct(admin);` then I get this error. the admin is = to msg.sender which is the first account in the ganache so I don't know what's wrong.

I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_gYUeaUoZs&index=11&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n) video. I have done all the other videos of this guy and everything is fine until now at minute 15:11 he does the final test and for him, it works but for me, it gives me the error above.

Anyone, please help

These is my test (javascript)

```
var CinoCoin = artifacts.require("./CinoCoin.sol");
var CinoCoinSale = artifacts.require("./CinoCoinSale.sol");


contract('CinoCoinSale', function(accounts) {
  var tokenInstance;
  var tokenSaleInstance;
  var admin = accounts[0];
  var buyer = accounts[1];
  var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000; // in wei 0.01 ether
  var tokensAvailable = 750000;
  var numberOfTokens;

  it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
    return CinoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenSaleInstance = instance;
      return tokenSaleInstance.address
    }).then(function(address) {
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, 'has contract address');
      return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
    }).then(function(address) {
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, 'has token contract address');
      return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    }).then(function(price) {
      assert.equal(price, tokenPrice, 'token price is correct');
    });
  });

  it('facilitats token buying', function() {
    return CinoCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      //Grab token instance first
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return CinoCoinSale.deployed();
    }).then(function(instance) {
      //Then grab token sale instance
      tokenSaleInstance = instance;
      //Provision 75% of all tokens to the token sale contract
      return tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, tokensAvailable, { from: admin})
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      numberOfTokens = 10;
      return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice })
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Sell', 'should be the "Sell" event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer, buyer, 'logs the account that purchased the tokens');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._amount, numberOfTokens, 'logs the number of tokens purchased');
      return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
    }).then(function(amount) {
      assert.equal(amount.toNumber(), numberOfTokens, 'increments the number of tokens sold');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(buyer);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), tokensAvailable - numberOfTokens);
      //Try to buy tokens different from the ether value
      return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: 1 });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei');
      return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(800000, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'connot purchase more tokens than available');
    });
  });

  it('ends token sale', function () {
    return CinoCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      //Grab token instance first
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return CinoCoinSale.deployed();
    }).then(function(instance) {
      //Then grab token sale instance
      tokenSaleInstance = instance;
      //try to end sale from account other than admin
      return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: buyer });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
      //End sale as admin
      return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'returns all unsold cino coins to admin');
      //Check that the token price was reset when selfFestruct was called
      return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    }).then(function(price) {
      assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0, 'token price was reset');
    });
  });
});
```

And this is my contract code (solidity)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./CinoCoin.sol";

contract CinoCoinSale {
  address admin;
  CinoCoin public tokenContract;
  uint256 public tokenPrice;
  uint256 public tokensSold;

  event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

  function CinoCoinSale(CinoCoin _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
    //Assign an admin / an external account connected to the blockchain that has certain priviliges
    admin = msg.sender;
    //Assign token contract
    tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    //Token Price how much the token will cost
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
  }

  //multiply function for
  function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
    require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
  }

  //Buy tokens
  function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
    //Require that the value is equal to tokens
    require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
    //Require that there are enough tokens in the contrat
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
    //Require the transfer is successful
    require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));
    //Keep track of number of tokens sold
    tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;
    //Trigger a sell event
    Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
  }

  //ending token CinoCoinSale
  function endSale()public {
    //Only an admin can end the end the sale
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    //Transfer the amount of token in the sale back to the admin
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(this)));
    //Destroy contract
    selfdestruct(admin);
  }
}
```

It says my test are passing when I comment out the `selfdestruct(admin);` so it seems to be a probelm with that

thanks for the help

Comment: Show your test(s).

Comment: what do you mean with tests like all my code? or what my terminal says?

Comment: I added the test which is written in javascript and my contract in solidity I hope this helps

Comment: I fixed it it was an error with the self destruction code thanks for the help anyway I am so glad I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad you fixed the error already. While looking at your code I noticed that the test file is quite difficult to follow because of the large promise chains. I converted the file to async/await, which might be easier to maintain and debug in the future.

I also noticed that you are trying to assert emitted events and reverts by manually checking the logs, and catching the revert exception. I actually wrote a library to make this a bit easier, so I added the code for this as well.

The library can be installed with npm:

`npm install truffle-assertions`

After this, the new test code should work. I hope this helps, and good luck with your Dapp development.

```
const CinoCoin = artifacts.require("CinoCoin");
const CinoCoinSale = artifacts.require("CinoCoinSale");
const truffleAssert = require("truffle-assertions");

contract('CinoCoinSale', function(accounts) {
  let tokenInstance;
  let tokenSaleInstance;
  let admin = accounts[0];
  let buyer = accounts[1];
  let tokenPrice = 1000000000000000; // in wei 0.01 ether
  let tokensAvailable = 750000;

  it('initializes the contract with the correct values', async function() {
    tokenInstance = await CinoCoin.deployed();
    tokenSaleInstance = await CinoCoinSale.deployed();

    assert.notEqual(tokenSaleInstance.address, 0x0, 'has contract address');
    assert.notEqual(await tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract(), 0x0, 'has token contract address');
    assert.equal(await tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice(), tokenPrice, 'token price is correct');
    assert.equal(await tokenSaleInstance.admin(), admin, 'admin is correct');
  });

  it('facilitates token buying', async function() {
    tokenInstance = await CinoCoin.deployed();
    tokenSaleInstance = await CinoCoinSale.deployed();
    await tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, tokensAvailable, { from: admin });

    const numberOfTokens = 10;
    const receipt = await tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice });

    truffleAssert.eventEmitted(receipt, 'Sell', (ev) => {
      return ev._buyer === buyer && ev._amount.toNumber() === numberOfTokens;
    });

    const tokensSold = await tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
    assert.equal(tokensSold.toNumber(), numberOfTokens, 'increments the number of tokens sold');

    const buyerBalance = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
    assert.equal(buyerBalance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);

    const tokenSaleBalance = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
    assert.equal(tokenSaleBalance.toNumber(), tokensAvailable - numberOfTokens);

    truffleAssert.reverts(
      tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: 1 }),
      null,
      'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei'
    );

    truffleAssert.reverts(
      tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(800000, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice }),
      null,
      'connot purchase more tokens than available'
    );
  });

  it('ends token sale', async function () {
    tokenInstance = await CinoCoin.deployed();
    tokenSaleInstance = await CinoCoinSale.deployed();

    truffleAssert.reverts(tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: buyer }), null, 'must be admin to end sale');

    await tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });

    const adminBalance = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
    assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(), 999990, 'returns all unsold cino coins to admin');

    const tokenPrice = await tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    assert.equal(tokenPrice.toNumber(), 0, 'token price was reset');
  });
});
```